# MSBuild now failing to resolve references

Tags: azure, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, azure-sdk-.net

We have a few projects within our CI environment which have been building successfully. Over the weekend, our IT team installed Azure SDK udpates, and since then, our project to not build anymore (even though they don't reference Azure).

The way we are building projects is

```
<MSBuild Condition="'$(BuildProject)' != ''" Projects="@(Projects)"
         Properties="Platform=$(Platform);Configuration=$(Configuration);OutDir=$(TempProjectFilesPublish)\bin\;WebProjectOutputDir=$(TempProjectFilesPublish)"
         Targets="Build"
         ContinueOnError="false">
```

where @(Projects) is a reference to the Solution folder.

```
<Projects Include="$(BuildProject)"/>
```

The issue is around resolving project references. Nothing has changed over the weekend. The project references are correct, the csproj file has the appropriate values, no new projects or code changes have been made which is leading me to think something has been disrupted.

Wondering if anyone might know of any changes to MSBuild that would affect this?

Comment: Enable MSBuild logging (such as /v:diag) and analyze the failure.

Comment: What version of the Azure SDK did you have before? and you have now?

Answer (score 1):

This issue ended up being a bug in Azure SDK 2.3 with a conflict to Newtonsoft.JSON dll.

The SDK installs a 4.5 build version into the GAC, which is overriding any Newtonsoft references in projects to 4.0.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/850425/windows-azure-vs-tools-breaking-msbuild-for-web-projects

Microsoft have stated this will be fixed in 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same problem with Azure SDK v2.9. I've fixed the build for the moment by uninstalling "Microsoft Azure Library for .NET v2.9".

P.S.: Unfortunately, the link provided in the answer by mickyjtwin no longer works.

P.P.S.: The following question seems to be related:
[Visual Studio keeps overwriting NewtonSoft.Json.DLL with an older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490967/visual-studio-keeps-overwriting-newtonsoft-json-dll-with-an-older-version/)