# Why do I have files from "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deplay V3" in my c# project's bin/Debug directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have a visual studio 2019 solution with a few projects that consist of mostly c# class libraries.  This solution is never 'deployed' and is always run locally by anyone who uses it.  Part of what we do for one of our test projects to work is put certain dll's we use into our bin/Debug folder.  One of these is Newtonsoft.Json.dll for example.  We have a specific version of that dll that we're required to use.

This is something that is usually done once, the first time we run a test in that project.  This all works fine.  However, whenever there is a code change and the project builds, for whatever reason all the files that are in "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3" are copied into our projects bin/Debug directory and overwriting any of the same files already there (Newtonsoft.Json.dll being one of them), and it's a different version which then breaks our projects dependency on that version of the dll.  It's worth nothing there are also a bunch of random other files/folders in that Web Deploy directory that get copied over that our project does not need to be there.

I've checked all build events, and searched the entire solution to see if we reference that directory at all which we don't.  I've tried googling similar issues, but almost all of what I can find is related to how to use Microsoft Web Deploy (which as far as I can tell we're not, and intentionally as I mentioned we don't deploy any of this code).

If anyone has any insight on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Probably the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157957/313445